# Craete Batches from Textarea input list and loop through function with delay php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a function that calls an API but want to create batches and call these every x second.

My form contains a textarea (Titles) where a list is added and are formatted SKU|Title on each line.

Within my code take each line and split where pipe is, i use the SKU part to know where the search terms belongs to and the Title part is used on the API search.

What i need to do now is split the 1000 (or however amount) inputted search lines into smaller batches, like 10 searches every 5 seconds and work through the titles.

Current Setup

```
<?php

function search_items($title, $filetype, $resultamount) {

  foreach(explode("\r\n", $title) as $line) {

  $strip = explode("|",$line);

  // This is where the API Runs
  // I use $strip[1] to get the Title to search in the API request

  }

}

?>
```

I think the below could work but kept getting errors like array to string error

```
$batches_of = 10;
$search_array = explode("\r\n", $title);
$batch = array_chunk($search_array, $batches_of);
foreach($batch as $b) {

  foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    print $key;
  }
 sleep (5);
}
```

Update

Ok so i have been trying this for a while and seem to have got something working and looks to do as intended, no errors and take a while but its as expected (note this is not a production model), any feedback on the below?

```
// Title = Multiple Lines from Textarea, Example Title 32306|Samsung Galaxy S20 256GB Black
// Filetype = I have a custom If / Else statement, if form has one selection display it differently (File Type 1 or 2)
// ResultAmount = How many results do i want to retrieve for each searched title, Example 1 - 10
function search_items($title, $filetype, $resultamount) {

// Set the amount of Batches to create from the Total Submitted amount in form
$batch_of = 10;
// Create array for each line item
$my_array = explode("\r\n", $title);
// Create array Batches
$batch = array_chunk($my_array, $batch_of);

foreach($batch as $line) {

  foreach ($line as $key => $value) {

    // Seperate the line items to Get SKU ($strip[0]) and get Title ($strip[1])
    $strip = explode("|",$value);
    // API request variables using CURL
    $endpoint = 'http://web.com/services/search';
    // The Query, now i will use the Product Name and appende $query to my search URL
    $query = ''.str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|()[]-'), '%20', $strip[1]).'';
    
    // My API Data and responses will be below

  }

 // Wait 2 Seconds before the next batch
 sleep (2);
}


}
```

Comment: Looking up like this will increase the response time of your server.

Comment: If you are getting an error, then PLEASE, Show us ALL the error message not a summary

Comment: You divided the code, please put it together. The second part goes in: "This is where the API Runs"? With the error, you should get the line, to which one correspond in your code? Put also an example of the value passed to the function as $title

Comment: Concatenating strings with empty strings is an amazingly common and useless practice.  I'll never understand it.

Comment: My feedback is non-resolving advice which is why I did not answer.  `''.str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|()[]-'), '%20', $strip[1]).''` does not benefit from those leading and trailing empty strings.  I don't have any advice about resolving your task.  (your ping didn't work because you misspelled my screenname)

Comment: My remarks gave you actionable insights.  You are free to be angry if you want -- I cannot stop you.  If I could resolve your task, I'd post an answer.  I don't yet know if this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).  Why do you need to do this?